# ZF2.4 takes to long to run phpunit with code coverage enabled

Tags: php, unit-testing, jenkins, zend-framework2, code-coverage

I'm having trouble with the speed of the Code Coverage.

I'm using ZF2 2.4 with a dozen modules installed by composer.
When I run tests without code coverage, with results in 5 minutes. In Jenkins the full build takes 15 minutes.

With code coverage enabled, the entire build took from 0:00 to 5:30 a.m..

Checking the results, I realized that the tests of Service / Repository / Controller classes are taking on average 2.10 minutes each. What is terrible.

I am extremely new to tdd development, could reach 100% code coverage, the system has three modules and a 10 entities.

The only problem I found was that I had mastery in creating mocks, then was unable mockar all application services, for example, the Repository / Service / Controller are adding, reading, updating and deleting the test database in real time.

As my time is short, my main question is whether the problem is really the mocks that are not correct because if the code coverage uses the meta information of which folders are read, should go into shock when you begin to enter the Vendor folder, Doctrine etc.

So this may be the main problem? not have done mocks the connections from the bank?

In my current technical knowledge, it would make much difference the mocks, but here where I work to this day no one has used mock and am trying to revolutionize.

The principle already applied all techniques that are described in the posts of the internet and other questions that are here in stackoverflow, is there any new technique to speed up code coverage?

There is a manual focused on a full explanation of how to speed up code coverage for PHP? a full explanation?

Thanks for listening.

Edit:

Codeception suite module config:

```
namespace: ColumnNotNull
actor: Tester
paths:
    tests: test
    log: build/coverage
    data: test/_data
    helpers: test/_support
settings:
    strict_xml: true
    bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
    colors: true
    memory_limit: 1024M
coverage:
    whitelist:
          include:
              - src/*
          exclude:
              - src/ColumnNotNull/Fixture/*
              - src/ColumnNotNull/Module.php*
    blacklist:
          include:
              - build/*
              - data/*
              - language/*
              - public/*
              - schema/*
              - test/*
              - view/*
              - src/ColumnNotNull/Fixture/*
```

Codeception Unit suite module Config:

```
class_name: UnitTester
modules:
    enabled: [Asserts, UnitHelper, Db]
    config:
      Db:
          dsn: 'mysql:dbname=pibernews;host=localhost'
          user: 'piber'
          password: 'secret'
          dump: data/column-not-null.mysql.sql
coverage:
    enabled: true
    remote_enable : false
```

Codeception Project Suite

```
include:
  - module/Column
  - module/ColumnImage
  - module/ColumnNotNull
paths:
  log: build
settings:
  colors: true
```

With codeception I can run multiple tests from different modules with merge results.

Is one project, with three modules. With Acceptance and Functional tests. Acceptance + Functional takes 15 min to run, unit with code coverage takes five hours.

Without code coverage take 10 min to run all unit tests. It's acceptable. But I want to take code coverage time down because five hours is a not acceptable.

Edit 2:

```
<?php
// This is global bootstrap for autoloading
include 'unit/GearBaseTest/ZendServiceLocator.php';

$zendServiceLocator = new \GearBaseTest\ZendServiceLocator();
```

_bootstrap.php file

```
<?php
namespace GearBaseTest;

use Zend\Loader\AutoloaderFactory;
use Zend\Mvc\Service\ServiceManagerConfig;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager;
use Zend\Test\PHPUnit\Controller\AbstractHttpControllerTestCase;

class ZendServiceLocator
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->chroot();

        $zf2ModulePaths = array(
            dirname(dirname(realpath(__DIR__ . '/../../')))
        );

        if (($path = $this->findParentPath('vendor'))) {
            $zf2ModulePaths[] = $path;
        }

        if (($path = $this->findParentPath('module')) !== $zf2ModulePaths[0]) {
            $zf2ModulePaths[] = $path;
        }

        $this->initAutoloader();

        $env = getenv('APP_ENV') ?  : 'testing';


        $applicationConfig = include \GearBase\Module::getProjectFolder().'/config/application.config.php';

        $config = array(
            'module_listener_options' => array(
                'module_paths' => $zf2ModulePaths,
                'config_glob_paths' => array(
                    sprintf('config/autoload/{,*.}{global,%s,local}.php', $env)
                )
            ),
            'modules' => $applicationConfig['modules']
        );


        $serviceLocator = new ServiceManager(new ServiceManagerConfig());
        $serviceLocator->setService('ApplicationConfig', $config);
        $serviceLocator->get('ModuleManager')->loadModules();
        $this->serviceLocator = $serviceLocator;
    }

    public function getServiceManager()
    {
        return $this->getServiceLocator()->get('ServiceManager');
    }

    public function chroot()
    {
        $rootPath = dirname($this->findParentPath('module'));
        chdir($rootPath);
    }

    protected function findParentPath($path)
    {
        $dir = __DIR__;
        $previousDir = '.';
        while (! is_dir($dir . '/' . $path)) {
            $dir = dirname($dir);
            if ($previousDir === $dir) {
                return false;
            }
            $previousDir = $dir;
        }
        return $dir . '/' . $path;
    }

    public function getEntityManager()
    {
        if (!isset($this->entityManager)) {
            $this->entityManager = $this->getServiceLocator()
            ->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
        }
        return $this->entityManager;
    }

    public function getServiceLocator()
    {
        return $this->serviceLocator;
    }

    public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        if (!isset($this->serviceLocator)) {
            $this->serviceLocator = $serviceLocator;
        }
        return $this->serviceLocator;
    }

    protected function initAutoloader()
    {
        $vendorPath = $this->findParentPath('vendor');

        $zf2Path = getenv('ZF2_PATH');

        if (! $zf2Path) {
            if (defined('ZF2_PATH')) {
                $zf2Path = ZF2_PATH;
            } elseif (is_dir($vendorPath . '/ZF2/library')) {
                $zf2Path = $vendorPath . '/ZF2/library';
            } elseif (is_dir($vendorPath . '/zendframework/zendframework/library')) {
                $zf2Path = $vendorPath . '/zendframework/zendframework/library';
            }
        }

        if (! $zf2Path) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                'Unable to load ZF2. Run `php composer.phar install` or' . ' define a ZF2_PATH environment variable.'
            );
        }

        if (file_exists($vendorPath . '/autoload.php')) {
            include $vendorPath . '/autoload.php';
        }
        include $zf2Path . '/Zend/Loader/AutoloaderFactory.php';

        AutoloaderFactory::factory(array(
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'autoregister_zf' => true,
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/' . __NAMESPACE__
                )
            )
        ));
    }
}
```

ZendServiceLocator.php grabber.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. If you are running code coverage on everything including the contents of the vendor folder I would expect this to take extraordinarily long. Otherwise, perhaps you could explain a bit more how your tests are setup. IMHO you want to use mocks sparingly, and most of your tests should not need to touch the database.

Comment: I recognize that I have difficulty in expressing this issue, thank you for helping me. So my tests should test only the files in the modules, but when the Repository inserts a row in the table, extra files example "Doctrine \ Orm \ EntityManager" are called, for the persist and flush i'm not using Mock. The code coverage settings are restricted only to folders that I need, my main question is: all classes used by the unit test are also used for code coverage, to its maximum depth, causing overhead information and causing exorbitant delay?

Comment: As I said, no one among my colleagues use code coverage and I am the first in my business I use, so I understand that by using restricted settings of code coverage would be enough to not calculate with the vendor folder. It will be a high cost to create mock for the most critical tests, like to make sure that this is a major cause of delay. The settings that i setup to PHPUnit + Code coverage work are very basic, but I omit them if necessary, which settings can be problem in time code coverage? Then I post here and we can check one by one.

Comment: Could you add your phpunit config file to your question if it isn't too large?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to whitelist the modules folder.

Comment: Also, unit tests should never hit the DB. That'll slow things down as well. If you need to hit the DB save that for Integration tests.